# How can I use get methods in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, try-catch

This assignment is comprised of creating a program to read up to (but not more) 25 test grades, then report the number of grades entered; and compute the arithmetic mean (average) and standard deviation of the grades.  I don't understand how to use the get methods I have created so I can implement it in my program.  Here is my code so far

```
package my.meancalculator;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MeanCalcUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private double average;
private double stdDeviation;
public double[] gradeArray;
public int numElem;
public double sum;
public int i;
public double numGrades;

public MeanCalcUI() {
    initComponents();
}

public double getAverage(double[] gradeArray, int numElem) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
        sum = sum + gradeArray[i];
    }

    return (sum / numElem);
}

public double getStdDev(double[] gradeArray, int numElem, double average) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
        sum = sum + Math.pow((gradeArray[i] - average), 2);
    }

    return Math.sqrt(sum / numElem);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnEnterGradesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               


    gradeArray = new double[25];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    boolean enterGrades = true;

    while (enterGrades) {
        try {
            String gradeInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                    "Enter Grade",
                    "Enter Grade",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            if ((gradeInput != null) && (gradeInput.length() > 0)) {

                gradeArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(gradeInput);

                average = getAverage;  

                numElem = numGrades + 1;  //right here I know it doesn't work but i have no idea on how to make it the total of the grades entered.  numElem is what the sum is getting divided by to find the average

                txtNumGrades.setText((numGrades) + "");

                txtMean.setText(average);

                txtStdDeviation.setText(stdDeviation);
            } else {
                enterGrades = false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "Your input must be numeric!",
                    "Bad Data!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }


    }


}
```

Also, I don't know how I can make another catch block in case the user enters more than 25 grades.  Here is my program guidelines from my teacher so you can have a better understanding on what it looks like and what is exactly being asked. http://homepages.uc.edu/~thomam/OOProg_1/assignment5.html

Can you guys help me out?

EDIT: Another question.  How can I make the variable numElem work?  I don't know how I can make that equal to the sum of all the grades entered.

Comment: From assumption: `average = getAverage;` should be `average = getAverage(/* passing your params*/);`. And for showing other `JOptionPane` popup message, you dont have to use `catch block`. Just a simple counter condition with `if` will work.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you are asking about is trying to access those other methods you wrote, like `getAverage()`. You need to always pass those methods parameters; a name without parentheses after it is treated as just a variable, but through the magic of syntax the moment you put some parentheses with parameters, it becomes a method call: `getAverage(gradeArray, numberOfGradesInput)`.

That said, there are faster ways to do most of what you're working on.

```
////////// CLASS FIELDS //////////
private double[] gradeArray = new double[25];
private int numberOfGradesInput = 0;
// You do not need any other fields! None! This is all you need to remember!



////////// BUTTON PRESSED //////////
if (numberOfGradesInput == 25) {
    // We've already finished entering the max # of grades
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "You've already entered the maximum of 25 grades.",
            "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
do {
    String gradeInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter Grade",
            "Enter Grade",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    // When we receive empty/null input, we're done entering grades
    if (gradeInput == null || gradeInput.length() == 0) break;

    double gradeValue = 0d; // Set to avoid 'may be unset' compiler error
    try {
        gradeValue = Double.parseDouble(gradeInput);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Your input must be numeric!",
                "Bad Data!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        continue; // start over again
    }

    // Put the grade into the array and update the number of grades entered
    gradeArray[numberOfGradesInput] = gradeValue;
    numberOfGradesInput++;

    // Add to the grade total
    txtNumGrades.setText(Integer.toString(numberOfGradesInput));

    // ---> You should look at using a number formatter so you don't get a million digits
    double gradeAverage = getAverage(gradeArray, numberOfGradesInput);
    txtMean.setText(Double.toString(gradeAverage));

    double standardDeviation = getStdDev(gradeArray, numberOfGradesInput, gradeAverage);
    txtStdDeviation.setText(Double.toString(standardDeviation));
} while (numberOfGradesInput < 25);
```

This code should work a bit more smoothly. Notice how it keeps track of the total number of grades input in `numberOfGradesInput` and only loops until either a blank entry is encountered or it's reached its maximum. Using `enterGrades` to track whether you're in the loop works, but the `break` statement is a much faster, cleaner, and more readable way to do it.

I must warn you to be extremely cautious of your fields! You are declaring a bunch of `public` fields at the top, then using them as local variables and loop variables. You are even *hiding* some of these variables with parameter names:

```
public int numElem;
```

-vs-

```
public double getAverage(double[] gradeArray, int numElem) {
```

This should be avoided to maintain clean code and avoid bugs. The best way to do it is to avoid using public fields *whenever possible*. By and large, if you only need a value in a certain method once at a time and don't need to remember it in between executions, it should not be a field, let alone a public one. Use instance variables inside your method instead! If possible, create these variables *only inside their own loop* rather than reusing them. Think of it this way: the farther away a variable can be touched, the more can go wrong. A quick example:

You defined the field `public int i;`. Let's say you're using that as a loop variable in `getAverage()`: `for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {`. Now, you also want to use a loop in a method called, say, `enterGrades()`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    getAverage(gradeArray, i);
}
```

Every time you jump over to `getAverage()`, it's messing with the *exact same value* you're trying to use to control the *other* loop you're already in. Problems will occur!

Again, if you don't need variables outside their loop, define them inside it: `for (int i = 0; ...`. If you need to know what number it ended on, just define a local variable right before the loop. And even if you aren't using them, defining fields like `public int i` when you are accustomed to using those names for loops etc. is just inviting disaster: if you forget to define your local variable `i`, your IDE probably won't warn you that you're using the `public` field.

Best of luck.

Comment: Wow. I can't even thank you enough.  I've been working on this for so long and you were the only person  to fully explain this to me. I seriously can't thank you enough, seriously.  There is only one problem though, it is required for me to use the getAverage method and I am also required to show an error message when the user enters more than 25 grades.  Maybe there is some left out code or something but I don't know where I would put it.  Also, what does your comment of boolen enterGrades = true; mean?

Comment: Well, you're no longer actually using `enterGrades`; as I pointed out, while having a running `boolean` value to keep track of whether you want to stay in the loop will _work_ it's much better to use actual control statements to leave the loop when you're done. As for displaying the error when you go over... well, when this code finishes asking for the 25th grade, it actually _stops asking_ -- as you can see, if `numberOfGradesEntered` is 25 when it loops around it just stops. So, it isn't even possible to enter more. Hopefully this should suffice in place of an ugly error.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't really matter all that much, I can/should change the way the loop works, from `while (numberOfGradesEntered < 25) { /*dostuff*/ }` to `do { /*dostuff*/ } while (numberOfGradesEntered < 25);` ... because, well, `numberOfGradesEntered` was set to 0 right before the loop, and checking to see if it's 25 or more as soon as you've done that is a bit silly. _//change made_

Comment: See, that's the thing... The user is not required to enter 25 grades; they can actually enter as many grades as they want.  So I can just enter 6 grades and then end the program, but if the user enters more than 25 grades it will show an error message.  Also, just to clear things up, the boolean is completely taken out of the code?

Comment: If you didn't write the `getAverage()` method, then you can just change `gradeAverage = gradeTotal / numberOfGradesEntered;` to `gradeAverage = getAverage(gradeArray, numberOfGradesEntered);`. It's a pretty silly way of doing it, but it should work. **On the other hand** if this is meant to allow you to enter a couple grades at a time and look at the results in between... you should indeed make `numberOfGradesEntered` a field in the class, and make sure to use the `while`-first loop (because you don't know what its value is going in).

Comment: Yeah, you don't ever use that boolean and shouldn't need to. `break` and `continue` are more than enough for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you must have an error message pop up, it would be good to do it when they push the button, and before you ask the user to spend time entering data that will be thrown away. Just check to see if `numberOfGradesEntered == 25` (which would be a field of the class instead of an instance variable, in this case) and if it is, spit out an error and `return;`.

Comment: Could you edit your code so I could see how you test if they entered more than 25 grades? I'm a little bit confused on the wording.

Comment: Also, the user does not enter all the grades at once.  They enter a number then click ok; it will then keep asking for an input until the user hits ok or cancel when the text field is blank

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're trying to do now. Answer code edited to allow you to enter grades over several occasions and whatnot. Notice that you ONLY need to keep the actual grades entered so far and how many there were.

Comment: If you really wanted to use a more efficient averaging method, you could also keep a running total here and divide by the number entered like I was doing at first, but as you said they demand you use their method that recalculates it every time. In practice it's a negligible waste of time, but if you care about that sort of thing it's good to make code that runs quickly if you can.

Comment: I know it's such a waste of time to use the getAverage method but I'm being forced to use it.  One more quick question, would I just use a default number format if I wanted to make them decimals?  Some of the numbers I input have a decimal and don't

Comment: The default number formatter is the one that outputs the full precision of the number. You can get a new `java.text.DecimalFormat`, like put `private final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0##");` in your class (or whatever pattern you like), then use `formatter.format(gradeAverage)` to get a better-looking output string for the floating-point values inside your method.

Comment: By the way, after running the program and checking everything there is one thing that does not happen, the error message when the user enters more than 25 grades.  Nothing pops up t just returns to the jframe.  Should I make numberOfGradesInput >25?

Comment: Did you include the clause up at the top that checks if you've gotten 25 grades input? With the message box? If you already have that in there, try commenting it out and just pop up a message box that displays what `numberOfGradesInput` equals. Also, take note that I kept on screwing up up above and writing `numberOfGradesEntered` instead of `numberOfGradesInput`.

Answer (score 1):

**This line of code:**

```
average = getAverage;  // from your if((gradeInput != null) && (gradeInput.length() > 0)) block;
```

The "getAverage(args)", the average = getAverage() <-- requires parameters to be passed into the method for further operation;

Replace "args" in the brackets with the parameters it requires and it should work;

Comment: The parameters it requires? What do you mean by this?  Would I add what the get method has into to the parantheses?  like average = getAverage(double[] gradeArray, int numElem) ?? I don't know how I can make numElem work so I can't do that.

Comment: The parameters you pass into the brackets are your gradeArray and numElem without type specification - method has already been declared and it knows what types should be passed into it. With regards to numElem - if I understand it right it is the length of your Array, if so there is a method ".length" which can be used for an array to get its length.

Comment: Wouldn't a .length method be for a string value to find how many letters are in a a string input?  Would that not be different for the amount of numbers in an array?

Comment: It does that to - you should read more about Java basics. There are some tutorials I can recommend. In your case by using length you would get the number of elements in the array.